# LSTM input reshape for multi variate data

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a data set with multiple inputs and outputs which I want to use with Keras LSTM. I am trying to figure out how the data needs to be reshaped.

The original data is following:

```
Time, Temp(X1), Pressure(X2), Stress(Y1), Life(Y2)          
1,  T1, P1, S1, L1
2,  T2, P2, S2, L2
3,  T3, P3, S3, L3
4,  T4, P4, S4, L4
5,  T5, P5, S5, L5
6,  T6, P6, S6, L6
```

We can use 2 previous values of Temperature, Pressure, Stress and Life to estimate the current value of Stress and Life. Thus using a lookback/timesteps of 2, we can use i can re-arrange my data to the following: 
X train matrix becomes of shape (4,10):

```
T1, P1, T2, P2, T3, P3, S1, L1, S2, L2
T2, P2, T3, P3, T4, P4, S2, L2, S3, L3
T3, P3, T4, P4, T5, P5, S3, L3, S4, L4
T4, P4, T5, P5, T6, P6, S4, L4, S5, L5
```

Y train matrix becomes of shape (4,2):

```
 S3, L3
 S4, L4
 S5, L5
 S6, L6
```

Keras requires input to be reshaped into [samples, time steps, features]

```
samples=4
timesteps/lookback=2
Original data X features=2
```

But it is not possible to reshape X train matrix of (4, 10) into (4,2,2). So, where is the catch?

Also, what should the Y train matrix be shaped to?

Comment: you must replace time index 6 and 7 by 5 and 6

Answer (score 1):

You want to predict the nth value from n-1 and n-2. Therefore you create a "sliding window" on your data to create samples.

data @ T1 and T2 to predict T3

data @ T2 and T3 to predict T4

and so on until

data @ T4 and T5 to predict T6

so you'll end up with 4 sample, defined by X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 from the previous 2 time steps

Your input data will be

```
X = [[[T1, P1, S1, L1]
      [T2, P2, S2, L2]],
     [[T2, P2, S2, L2],
       T3, P3, S3, L3]],
     [[T3, P3, S3, L3]
       T4, P4, S4, L4]],
     [[T4, P4, S4, L4],
       T5, P5, S5, L5]]]
```

and the values you want to predict

```
y = [[S3, L3],
     [S4, L4],
     [S5, L5],
     [S6, L6]]
```

Comment: I am trying to predict current values of Y1 and Y2, using current values of X1 and X2 and previous values of X1, X2, Y1, Y2.

Comment: @trumee i'll edit my answer to predict current Y1, Y2 only from past X1 and X2

Comment: I have updated the X matrix above. In your first sample why did you omit the current values T3 and P3. They should also be used to estimate S3, L3.

Comment: @trumee actually not sure you can have observations at each timestep defined by a different number of features (4 for the past observations and 2 for the current one).

Comment: Right, the X matrix you have posted is in the right order [samples, time steps, features] so it doesnt need to be reshaped, right?